# "Variable does not exist" when I'm try to make a query with Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm beginner in Elixir, and I'm trying to make a query, with:

```
def posts_liked(%{id: id}, _info) do
  query = from u in Like, where: u.user_id == ^id
  {:ok, Repo.all(query)}
end
```

But, say that the variable `u` doesn't exists. But, [in oficial doc](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-query-expressions) have this same code, and other manuals too. How to fix it?

My `Like` scheme is:

```
schema "likes" do
  belongs_to :post, Myapp.Post, foreign_key: :post_id
  belongs_to :user, Myapp.User, foreign_key: :user_id

  timestamps()
end
```

Comment: Do you have `import Ecto.Query` in this module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're missing `import Ecto.Query` in this module. Without that, Ecto thinks `from` is a normal function, not a macro, and starts checking that the arguments are valid. The first argument is `u in Like`, which desugars to `Enum.member?(Like, u)`. `Like` is a valid value but there's no variable named `u` and Elixir throws that error. Adding

```
import Ecto.Query
```

or

```
import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]
```

to the module will fix this problem.