# Should I use require or import while using Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm relatively new to the language, and have already read the [differences](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) between the `require` and `import` keywords. Nevertheless I can't seem to understand the following behavior while using Ecto.

So, I want to extract a `fragment` that's commonly used to get a value from a json field. Reading the Ecto [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2) I understand that in order to extract a `fragment` I have to wrap it on a `dynamic` macro. So I'm trying to implement it like this:

```
defmodule Foo do
  require Ecto.Query

  ...

  defp foo_fragment() do
    dynamic([t], fragment("?.json->>'foo'", t))
  end
end
```

To which I get the following warning

```
variable "t" does not exist and is being expanded to "t()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
```

Which seems reasonable enough, but isn't mentioned on the Ecto documentation. Looking for answers I found this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741389/variable-does-not-exist-when-im-try-to-make-a-query-with-ecto) where is recommended to use `import Ecto.Query`. I also noticed that it's used that way on the Ecto docs examples (probably for aesthetic reasons though).

To my surprise upon trying it, the warning on the previous code it's gone.

Is there something I'm missing regarding these keywords? I thought both were equivalent regarding the usage of macros, `require` being a more conservative approach as to keeping namespaces apart. Thanks!

Comment: I checked the warning thing out of curiosity, but I couldn't reproduce it.
If you want to use `require`, you can't just call `dynamic` like this, it will be treated as an undefined function (and you get an error as well as warnings). It should be `Ecto.Query.dymamic(...)`, in which case I didn't see any warning.

Answer (score 3):

While `import` is probably the most standard way to work with `Ecto.Query`, you can perfectly use `require` as well if you prefer to avoid bringing all its macros and functions into your module namespace.

All the following are equivalent and work without any warning:

```elixir
defmodule FragmentImport do
  import Ecto.Query

  def foo_fragment() do
    dynamic([t], fragment("?.json->>'foo'", t))
  end
end
```

With `require`, `dynamic/2` will be undefined so you need to use the qualified name `Ecto.Query.dynamic/2`:

```elixir
defmodule FragmentRequire do
  require Ecto.Query

  def foo_fragment() do
    Ecto.Query.dynamic([t], fragment("?.json->>'foo'", t))
  end
end
```

If it feels too verbose, you can use the [`:as` option](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#require/2-alias-shortcut) to alias the module as an intermediary solutions:

```elixir
defmodule FragmentRequireAs do
  require Ecto.Query, as: Query

  def foo_fragment() do
    Query.dynamic([t], fragment("?.json->>'foo'", t))
  end
end
```

You can pick whichever style you prefer: `require` can help removing the ambiguity to know where a macro/function comes from, but when working with Ecto people are usually familiar with it enough so there is little ambiguity in practice.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title of your post, normally you only need to specify `import Ecto.Query` at the top of a module that makes use of the `Ecto` queries.

To clarify the info in the body of your post: the error you are getting has nothing directly to do with `Ecto` or the differences between `include` and `require`: the error is telling you that the `t` variable is **not set**, so the compiler is instead treating it as a function name (remember that parentheses are optional in Elixir, so treating it like `t()` is a reasonable attempt at resolving it to a usable value).

Usually when I use `fragment`, the variable I am using is passed into the function, e.g.:

```
defmodule Foo do

  import Ecto.Query

  def get(name) do
    from u in User,
      where: fragment("lower(username) = ?", ^String.downcase(name))
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get what you are saying. But as I said, I'm trying to precisely extract a `fragment` for reuse on the other parts of the code. If you check the documentation on `dynamic` it shows an example where the variables are also defined "in place".
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#dynamic/2 
Also, that doesn't explain why the error disappears with `import` but does appear using `require`.

Comment: I think the differences in the errors when using `import` vs. `require` is probably a red herring -- my guess is the messages change because of how the macros are evaluated differently, but per your original question, you should use only `import Ecto.Query`.   Perhaps you should consider posting a separate question that clarifies exactly what you're trying to accomplish with your dynamic/fragment query.